# Reverse sign of number stored as string

Tags: php

This is a trivial operation but it has revealed some tricky points.
I have a string in PHP, say `'234.00'`. I want to convert that to a negative number, and preferably get a string in the end. So the test cases *should* be

```
'234.00'  ==> '-234.00'
'-234.00' ==> '234.00'
'0.00'    ==> '0.00'
```

The original code was

```
$signReversed = $stringNumber * -1.0
```

but that has problems because I really need a string for consistency with other code. So I tried

```
$signReversed = strval($stringNumber * -1.0)
```

but this fails on the last test case, because I get `'-0'` -- negative zero as a string.

Suggestions on the best way to do this?

Comment: $number = "-" . $number; use that and it will always be a string, no need to convert anything. just add 1 check if($number == "-0") $number = "0";. put it in a function

Comment: That doesn't work for -234.00.

Comment: Boo negative vote with no comment. Seems too simple or trivial, I guess? The question still seems reasonable to me, and I received multiple wrong answers, so it's not dead simple.

Comment: use substr for -234.00, substr("-234.00", 1);

Comment: Too complicated, I think, to have to check the string to see if it's negative or positive first, and then do the substring only if negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this

should work for small numbers, large numbers and strings can contain NULL bytes

```
function flipSign($stringNummer) {
   if ((string)$stringNummer !== $stringNummer) // fast !is_string check
      throw new Exception('input should be a string');
   return number_format($stringNummer * -1, 2, '.', '');
}

/**
 * NULL byte test 
 */
var_dump(flipSign("00\0.10"));   // string(5) "-0.10" 
var_dump(flipSign("-00\0.10"));  // string(4) "0.10"

var_dump(flipSign("00.10"));   // string(5) "-0.10" 
var_dump(flipSign("-00.10"));  // string(4) "0.10"

var_dump(flipSign("234.00"));   // string(7) "-234.00 
var_dump(flipSign("-234.00"));  // string(6) "234.00"

var_dump(flipSign("234.20"));   // string(7) "-234.20"
var_dump(flipSign("-234.20"));  // string(6) "234.20" 

var_dump(flipSign("100000.20"));   // string(10) "-100000.20"
var_dump(flipSign("-100000.20"));  // string(9)  "100000.20"
```

Comment: Perfect, although I can guarantee the input is not a string, so I can skip that first part.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the unary negation operator (-)?

```
$signReversed = "" . (-$stringNumber);
```

Comment: This returns a number, apparently, not a string.

Comment: Updated snippet to convert the number to a string.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'm going with the `number_format...` answer from Raymond because it works on works better with some other test cases that I neglected to put in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$stringVal = "234.00";
$negativeStringVal = strval(floatval($stringVal) * -1);
```

I think your problem is that PHP tries to convert your numbers to `int` but fails because of the decimals.

Edit: PHP Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/iay-rsc

Comment: Your php code also break with $stringVal = "234\0.00";   NULL Byte that terminates the string after 234.. ive posted a answer where thats fixed it also fixes the truncated zeros after '.'.

Comment: Fails on the zero test -- still gives back a negative zero.

Comment: Why not just test if the number is zero, and then not multiply in that case?

Comment: Because I want a one-liner. :-)

Answer (score 0):

something like this perhaps

```
$vals=array('234.00','-234.00','0');
$newvals=array();
foreach($vals as $val){
    $tmpval=$val*-1;
    array_push($newvals,"$tmpval");
}
var_export($newvals);
```

Comment: So the main part of your answer is `$val*-1` which is exactly what I had at the beginning. It fails on the `0` case.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$signReversed = strval(floatval($stringNumber) * -1.0)`

Comment: Fails on the zero test -- still gives back a negative zero.